# How to clear tomcat sever cache via java application?

Tags: java, tomcat

I am developing j2ee project. There when i do some changes using that deployed application using the browser, The change is not applying to the front-end. But if I restart the server(**tomcat 7**), then the change is there. So now I need to clear the tomcat server cache using my application. How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

In case you are talking about Hot Deployment which means to bring live changes to your application server without having to restart it, here is a link you can follow for [Tomcat Hot Deploy support](http://www.mulesoft.com/tcat/tomcat-deploy-procedures).

Otherwise, if you mean by `some changes`, modifications done into static web resources such as js or css files so you only need to clear youy browser cache then refresh to have the last version loaded.

Cheers.

Comment: if the static resources are part of the deployed war, then browser cache is not going to suffice

Comment: I just need to clear the cache of the server. Clearing browser cache is not sufficient

Comment: Could you more explain what do you mean by server cache?